# What is the control for hanging in Prince of Persia Retro?

Tags: ios, prince-of-persia

How can I hang on the iPad version of the game? This used to be possible on a PC.

Comment: This inspired me to go searching for an answer, upon which I discovered that it's free for iOS right now. So thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Hold the "Move Carefully" button while you are jumping up to a ledge or climbing backwards down one. You'll hang until you let go of the careful control, or until you climb up or drop down with the up/down controls.

You can initiate a jump or climb down and then quickly move your right thumb to the careful control while in mid-animation, and it will work just fine.